# Appcelerator Doesnt Accept Developer Certificate

Tags: authentication, certificate, appcelerator, account

Appcelerator made me crazy!!!

I'm trying to compile / test / build etc. but I stuck with the error below. First I thought it happened because I updated to El Capitan and gives these errors only for iOS builds.

Later,

I realized It happens when I try to build for Android on Windows.

Please help me guys,
I have done lots of things but I couldn't get solved this!

Logging out doesn't solved anything. Certificates also changed nothing. (On OS X)

Is it related with my account type on appcelerator platform or anything otherwise that I couldn't understand...

```
[ERROR] :  Developer Certificate Invalid. Please logout using `appc logout -D` and then re-login again.
2015-12-03T18:42:18.785Z | TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 100
2015-12-03T18:42:18.786Z | ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 100
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mustafa\.appcelerator\install\5.1.0\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\plugins\run.js:92:66)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
2015-12-03T18:42:18.787Z | TRACE  | Sending exit signal to titanium process:  3372
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Comment: Hi Anixrud, this sure sucks.

Could you follow [this guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Troubleshooting) to enable debug and trace logs so we can see a bit more of what is going on?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I solved the problem by using another Appcelerator Accout. I still don't know the problem. It is interesting that the problem solving by switching accout...

Comment: If you now switch back to the account that didn't work, does it still not work?

Comment: No, I haven't switch back yet. I haven't tried it. After days of effort, I don't want to interrupt my workflow. :) When I am available I will try that share in here...

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error was caused by non-english character used in my surname. I'd suggest you login to Appcelerator's dashboard and verify your account's details (first name, last name).

Comment: Are you serious :) I haven't thought that. But I think I have to check it. Thanks...

Comment: Did you check this? As I wrote in my case getting rid of such characters solved the issue.